# How to search an environment using ls() inside a function?

Tags: r, environment

I want to find a set of functions and save them, because I want to send them to a remote server in an Rdata file, and I don't want to install a new package on the server.

Although I am getting an error using the approach below, easier / better approaches are welcome.

**MWE:**

Here are two dummy functions:

```
abcd.fun.1    <- function() return(1)
abcd.fun.2    <- function() return(2)
```

I can identify the dummy functions:

```
ls()[grep('abcd', ls())]
```

But when I wrap this in a function:

```
 find.test <- function(x) {
     return(ls()[grep(x, ls())])
 }
 find.test('abcd')
```

The function returns `character(0)`

Ultimately I would like to

```
 save(find.test('abcd'), file = test.Rdata)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Why not use the `pattern=` argument to `ls`?
2. Calling `ls` inside a function lists the objects that exist within the
   function scope, *not* the global environment (this is explained in `?ls`).

If you want to list the objects in the global environment from a function, specify `envir=.GlobalEnv`.

```
x <- 1:10
f <- function() ls()
g <- function() ls(envir=.GlobalEnv)
h <- function() ls(envir=.GlobalEnv, pattern="[fg]")
f()
# character(0)
g()
# [1] "f" "g" "h" "x"
h()
# [1] "f" "g"
```

Comment: globalenv() is preferred these days

Comment: @hadley: could you explain why?

Comment: Hmmm, I could've sworn it suggested that in the documentation but I guess not. In that case it's just personal opinion: I think it's nicer to use a function than a global.

Answer (score 7):

You need to tell your function to list objects in an environment other than itself, e.g. the global environment.  (And while you're at it, you can also specify the regex pattern as an argument to `ls`.):

```
find.test <- function(x, envir=.GlobalEnv) {
  ls(pattern=x, envir=envir) 
}
```

See `?ls` for more info about `ls()` and `?environment` for other options to specify the environment.