# save(list = ls()) Inside function not working with Assign variables

Tags: r

I'm trying to use ls() with variables I've brought into a function's environment from the parent function, or the global environment.  I've seen this:

[How to search an environment using ls() inside a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142941/how-to-search-an-environment-using-ls-inside-a-function)

And this:

[rm(list = ls()) doesn't work inside a function. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46966847/rmlist-ls-doesnt-work-inside-a-function-why)

But I still have this problem: my ls() call is not returning the *assign* variables that I know are inside that function's environment.  I'm not trying to get the Global Environment, I want my function's environment.  What am I missing?

```
g = function() {
  e = environment()
  get("f",envir = parent.env(e))
  print(f)
  save(list=ls(envir = e),file = "U:/GitHub/FunctionDebug.RData")
}

h = function() {
  g()
}

f <- 1
h()

[1] 1 # So I know that my variable is seen by the function!
```

When I call load the file back into my Global Env, I get an empty namespace (other than e, the function environment.  This only happens for variables that I've assigned from another function's environment.  Why?

```
load("U:/GitHub/FunctionDebug.RData")
> ls()
[1] "e"
```

Comment: Why haven't you assigned the results of `get` to anything? At the very least, to find something in the environment `e`, I would expect to have to explicitly assign something to that environment in the first place, no?

Comment: Your variable `f` was seen by the function indeed, but there was nothing in the environment `e`. `f` was in the _parent environment_ of `e` but not in `e`.

Comment: @joran  How embarrassing...that was it!  I didn't realize `get` returned a value that needed to be assigned to something.